# JSON, JSONP and script tags

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am new to this and really confused about it. Forgive me if it sounds stupid. I want to embed content on another domain using script tags. I learnt that the page supplying the content has to be give a json answer. The page supplying the content is a php file which brings it from my database. How do i go abou this?

I tried a simple example of json but it did not work, what am i doing wrong?

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/test2.php?WrapperFunction=SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest">
```

test2.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest({"data" : "<pre>Some Html</pre>"});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP response for JSON-P should be:

- JSON-P, not a fragment of HTML with embedded JSON-P
- Call a function, so it shouldn't use the `function` keyword which defines one
- Call a function that exists
- Have the right content type

So in test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest(data) {
        // does stuff with the data object
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/test2.php?WrapperFunction=SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest">
```

and in test2.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
?>
SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest({"data" : "<pre>Some Html</pre>"});
```

Comment: The problem is i want to be able to give people a widget to embed using only the script tag. How do i do it without the top bit?

Comment: You stop using JSON-P and just provide them with a dynamically generated script with with embedded data. i.e. You put the top bit (**without** the script tags) in the main script.

Answer (score 0):

The `function` keyword is used to define a new function. Since JSONP calls an already existing function (called a "callback function"), you don't need this keyword, and it's causing problems because I don't believe that is even valid ECMAScript.